# What determines if `return false` in link's onclick attribute prevents navigation?

Tags: javascript, return

`Link 1` will not show the example site, but `Link 2` will. Why?

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bolvaritamas/FYX7s/) for the code below:

JS:

```
function myAlert(what) {
    alert(what);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="alert('Link 1');return false;">Link 1</a>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="myAlert('Link 2');return false;">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: They both work the same. Your fiddle doesn't work because you have the `myAlert` function inside the `body.onload()` function, so it isn't visible in the global scope that the `onclick` attribute uses. Change to `No wrap` and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/FYX7s/1/

Comment: `myAlert` is not defined (in the global scope): http://jsfiddle.net/y4Weg/

Comment: What an amateur mistake, I feel embarrassed for my question... Thank for all of you for the quick help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When viewing your fiddle, open the JS console (F12 on windows).  Click the second link.

You should see `Uncaught ReferenceError: myAlert is not defined`.  This is because `myAlert` is not in the global scope; jsfiddle scopes your JS code to an `onLoad` block automatically.  You can of course change this to `No wrap - in head` to get the correct behavior.

Here's a working version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krD2b/

Comment: So, to answer the question, "an error happening before it gets a chance to `return false;`." This is actually one reason for preferring `event.preventDefault()`, because you can do that first and not worry as much about errors messing you up.

Comment: But really, the problem is just specific to jsfiddle, not really a Javascript question.

Comment: @Barmar I added the jsfiddle tag to the question. Anyway, I have had this problem in my own code before making a simplified extract of it on jsfiddle. The only reason I haven't noticed the error previously in my console is that one of my collaborators had bypassed it by using [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com). So IMHO it's rather a "use your console" problem, not a jsfiddle one.

Comment: @TamásBolvári His question wasn't really about using jsfiddle. It's just that because he was using jsfiddle to test his code, and he didn't know about this feature of jsfiddle, he was misled into thinking there was a difference between the two codes.